# How to Downsample a DataFrame from a given date on a set frequency

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a Python dataframe (let's call it df), which has monthly (end) data beginning from 01/01/1998. I would like to have the same dataframe df, downsampled on a quarterly basis, but starting from 31/01/1998. 
Hence, after 31/01/1998, the next row should contain data as of 30/04/1998 and so on.

DataFrame.asfreq() seems to be the closest to my needs as it doesnt perform any aggregation like DataFrame.resample() but my ability to "start" from a given data seems limited.

---

```
LTM_Quarterly.head(5)
```

gives this output:

```
Date        Rate
1999-01-31  0.018957
1999-02-28  0.013514
1999-03-31  0.020833
1999-04-30  0.019920
1999-05-31  0.022222
```

But when I run the following code, as I have Date as index:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date

# test data, day first
startdate = date(1999, 1, 31) # Y M D

newdf = pd.DataFrame()

for index, row in LTM_Quarterly.iterrows():
    if index == startdate:
        print(index)
        startdate +=relativedelta(months=+3)
```

I am seeing only first two rows being printed. 
As a simple print(index) is printing two rows only, any assignment is also working only for 2 rows.

Any insights here?

Comment: to be sure, so you have data for every month and you want to down sample to quarterly without any aggregation? what about selecting every three rows then? or select the rows where the month are in [1,4,7,10]? maybe add an example and expected output

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to you want the exact result on the month end date, or an aggregated quarterly result.  The two are quite different - I concur with @Ben.T, a [mre] with I/O would be helpful.

Comment: I don't need aggregation. I think Petru's solution is what I need. Slightly disappointed that I don't have an easy one shot function in the pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: adapted to 'Month first' date format

Don't now how efficient, but something like this works:

```py
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date

# test data, month first
df = pd.DataFrame([{'date':'01/01/1998', 'c2':100}, 
{'date':'02/01/1998','c2':110}, {'date':'03/01/1998','c2':120},
{'date':'04/01/1998','c2':120},{'date':'04/01/1998','c2':120},
{'date':'06/01/1998','c2':120}])


startdate = date(1998, 1, 1) # Y M D

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=False)
newdf = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.set_index('date')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index.month == startdate.month:
        newdf = newdf.append(row)
        startdate +=relativedelta(months=+3)

print(newdf)
```

Edit2: Also, if you are **absolutely sure** your data is in order, you can select every 3rd row with the following:

```py
df.iloc[::3, :]
```

This will give the same result as above, **only if your data is ordered**

Comment: This solution is only returning the first two rows for me. Adding a minimal reproducible example in the OP

Comment: @Soham, That should't happen. Maybe you have a dfferent date format fro the example. maybe you have M D Y?

Comment: @Soham , I addapted the answer

Comment: So after 4/30, adding 3 months gives its 7/30. I have no data as 7/30. I have 7/31. And that is why the if clause fails and execution never enters the if-clause again.

Comment: @Soham , in this case you can add  .month to a date oject. Change this line: if index.date() == startdate to " if index.date().month == startdate.month:

Comment: So we will have to pick the last day of every 3 month, starting from 31st Jan. So 3 months after Jan is April, last day is 30th April. Similarly, 3 months after April is July, last day of July is 31st July

Comment: Yep . I do. In fact, I tweaked the if condition to index.month = startdate.month condition

Comment: No just index.month works fine. I tried index.date().month, it gives me an error.

Comment: My dataframe is sorted. So df[::3] worked like a charm! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by checking the `month` of the column Date and use `isin` like:

```
df_ = df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.month.isin([1,4,7,10])]
print (df_)
         Date      Rate
0  1999-01-31  0.018957
3  1999-04-30  0.019920
```

or if Date is index, you don't need `.dt` in the above code. Also if you want to generate the months from the first one (either 1, 2, or 3), you could try:

```
month_ = 1 #set which month here
df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.month.isin(range(month_, month_+12, 3))]
```